# Excel to keyboard Redirection

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, vba, excel

Im Searching for a windows application which would redirect all the entries in an excel sheet to a keyboard entry(Just like copy paste).Twist is that if there are 100 entries in one column of excel sheet 
with one entry in each cell(obviously), it should be copied to a single line text box by taking enter key itself after each cell being copied by itself until it finishes last entry in the excel sheet column(after each copy and enter our text box will be cleared by adding that entry to a list in our application).Is there any ways to develop such any application which would do the above job for me???. Irrespective of the content in the cell of an excel sheet, i need that content to be copied to the text box automatically one after the other. Its just like redirecting excel sheet entries to an a Keyboard entry.Please help me with this.Thank you....

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question: you have a huge list of values in one column in Excel. And you need to loop through all values, each time, you <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> a value from the current row, go to another application, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> the value over there, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I have done this task countless number of times.

I used a small macro recording application called [KeyText](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/KeyText.shtml) and many other [alternatives to KeyText](http://alternativeto.net/software/keytext/)

I personally worked with KeyText and loved it.

You simply need to "teach" it what to do with one row, and ask it to repeat the steps for the rest of the rows. You will be able to control the speed of which it repeats the steps to measure the productivity and increase it if needed.

You can type commands like:

```
{Wait 1} //to wait one second
{Ctrl+C} // to copy
{Alt+Tab} // to switch to the next window
{Ctrl+V} //paste
{Alt+Tab} //return to the previous window
{Down} // Go one cell down
```

You would then put all of the above in one unit of macro, and ask keytext to execute it over and over, until you interrupt it with <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

But don't worry, there is a wizard feature with a virtual keyboard so that you visually select keys that you want KeyText to press for you.

Comment: But without the rhythmic tapping of the copying and pasting, how will I ever improve my finger drum skills?  seriously, this is a great find.